# How to get string from XMLObject

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I am using xml2js to generate an XMLObject. And I can't find documentation how I can retrieve the string back from my XMLObject.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var xmlDoc = "";

parser.parseString(message, function(err,result){
    xmlDoc = result;
});
```

At this point I have my xmlObject stored in xmlDoc. So how can I retrieve the string from xmlDoc

XMLSerializer does not work because I use it on the server side.

Comment: What do you mean "*XMLSerializer does not work because I use it on the server side*" - do you need convert XML to string on server-side? If so, what language/platform?

Comment: Yes I have to do it on the server side and I am using javascript on the server. Also I installed node.js for it.

Comment: If you just need the string, why are you parsing as the XML into JS? Are you modifying it?

Comment: yeah i have to do some modifications between it. So for me its neccesary to create the xmlDoc and later on revert it to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) module only converts one-way from XML to JS, it will not re-serialize the JS object into XML.

If you want to parse XML, modify it, and then re-serialize it, [xmldom](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom) will probably do what you want. You will just have to work with the document using standard DOM functions rather than as an object.